# Google Cloud Messaging Fee for sending to many number of users

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I need to use Google Cloud Messaging to send new news as push notifications for over 6000 users, but I need to know the estimated costs for that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [GCM Overview](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm) doc:

> Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is a ***free service*** that enables developers to send messages between servers and client apps.

And if you're going to send push notifications to that number, all for the sole purpose of sending news updates, I suggest you look into [GCM Topic Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging).

Cheers! :D

Comment: you mean its a completely free service for no limit users per app ?

Comment: Yup. Totally free. For the whole world to use. There are some restrictions to the messaging. But when talking about cost, none. Absolutely free. Though I think there are some payed ***additional features***.